# What is the name of this piece?

Tags: classical-music

I recently came across a edit video of lang lang where he was playing a piece all thought he was not actually playing it because it was edited. I searched for it and found out its called RUNTAH MEDLEY BULEUD and on Shazam it said - Not afraid by Sangka pia. But over whole internet I only found 3-4 videos on it. Its a beautiful piano piece but still it is soo much infamous. Why’s that? Can u help me finding the original composer and song?

Comment: Sorry but this question is not on-topic because it is asking to *identify* a particular piece of music, see: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).